# derivative of the dominant eigenvalue

Tags: eigenvalues

In my reaseach, recently,  I came across of this problem where I have to compute, analytically,  the derivative of the dominant eigenvalue of the following matrix.

Let $D$ be a diagonal real $n \times n $ matrix $\text{diag} \{d_{1}, \dots , d_{n}\}$. Let A be an essentially nonnegative matrix (that is $a_{ij}\geq 0$, for all $i\neq j$). It is known that $r(A+D)$ is a convex function of $D$ (see ref), where $r(A+D)$ is the dominant eigenvalue of an $A+D$.

I need to find an expression for $\frac{\partial r(A+D)}{\partial D_{jj}}|_{D^{*}} $, where $D^{*}$ is a diagonal matrix. It would be great if someone can direct me on how to compute this derivative.

ref: @article{cohen1981convexity,
  title={Convexity of the dominant eigenvalue of an essentially nonnegative matrix},
  author={Cohen, Joel E},
  journal={Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society},
  volume={81},
  number={4},
  pages={657--658},
  year={1981}
}

Thank you.

Comment: Even in the $2x2$ case, this seems to be quite a complicated expression.

Comment: There was a typo in my question previously. I have edited it. I was hoping that i could get an expression for the derivative in terms of the eigenvectors of $(A+D)$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $r(A+D)$.

Comment: Link to the referenced article: http://lab.rockefeller.edu/cohenje/PDFs/090ConvexityDominantEigenvalueProcAMS1981.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Check out this paper:

[*Derivatives of the Perron root at an essentially nonnegative matrix and the group inverse of an $M$-matrix*](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022247X84901987)